# Probabilities for multiclass problem using OneVsRestClassifier do not sum to 1

Tags: python, probability, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass classification problem for various classifiers (random forest, SVM, NN) and I use OneVsRestClassifier to wrap my models. I want to use an interpretability method (LIME) which makes use of probabilities that sum to 1, but when I use the function predict_proba, the sum of the matrix does not always sum to 1.

It's a multiclass classification problem. I have checked my raw data, my binarized values, and my train/test data to check that there is no overlap of classes. Each instance has a distinct label (100, 010, or 001).

```
x = pd.read_pickle(r"x.pkl").values
y = pd.read_pickle(r"y.pkl").values

#  binarize labels for multilabel auc calculations
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

#  create train and test sets, stratified
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, stratify=y, test_size = 0.20, random_state=5)

rfclassifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=5, criterion = 'gini', bootstrap = True)
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(rfclassifier)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = classifier.predict(x_test)
probability = classifier.predict_proba(x_test)

#check probabilities
print(classifier.predict_proba([x_test[0]]).round(3))
print(classifier.predict_proba([x_test[1]]).round(3))
print(classifier.predict_proba([x_test[20]]).round(3))
```

The print statements show examples for label 1, 0, and 2 respectively. 
The outputs are `[[0.164 0.836 0.   ]]`, `[[0.953 0.015 0.   ]]`, and `[[0.01 0.12 0.96]]`. The last two (as well as many other instances) do not sum to 0 and prevent me from implementing the interpretability method.

Comment: I think it is a rounding error, did you check `classifier.predict_proba(x_test[20]]).sum()`?

Comment: @PV8 I did try but there is still an issue. The sum of each matrix should be 1 and it still doesn't work even if I don't round.

Comment: from the documentation of predict_proba in OneVsRestClassifier: Probability estimates.

The returned estimates for all classes are ordered by label of classes.

Note that in the multilabel case, each sample can have any number of labels. This returns the marginal probability that the given sample has the label in question. For example, it is entirely consistent that two labels both have a 90% probability of applying to a given sample.

Comment: @PV8 right, that is for multilabel cases. Mine is a multiclass problem; in the following line of documentation it says: "In the single label multiclass case, the rows of the returned matrix sum to 1."

Comment: you are right, could you give us the number of the sum?